# Boot Yocto on Beaglebone Black from SD-Card

Tags: linux, sd-card, beagleboneblack, yocto, u-boot

I'm currently trying to boot my **Beaglebone Black** with the *latest Yocto* version from a **SD-Card** without erasing the OS from the eMMC of my BBB.
The problem is that (although the SD-Card is inserted) the BBB keeps booting the eMMC image.

More details on the U-Boot an Linux versions are shown below:

**UBOOT**

```
U-Boot 2015.01-00001-gb2412df (Jan 29 2015 - 15:01:06)
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc (Linaro GCC 2014.11) 4.9.3 20141031 (prerelease) 
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) Linaro 2014.11-3-git 2.24.0.20141017
```

**Linux on BBB's eMMC**

```
Linux beaglebone 3.8.13-bone70 #1 SMP Fri Jan 23 02:15:42 UTC 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to press the boot-switch while resetiing / powering up:
See in this picture:

[BBB Switch Caption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwar1.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1** (MLO file)

> To force a boot from the microSD card, delete the MLO file in the
>   FAT partition of the eMMC.
>
> You can access this when the board is connected over the USB cable
>   and it appears as a thumbdrive.

from: http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBone_Black_FAQ#How_can_I_just_boot_from_the_microSD_instead_of_the_eMMC.3F

**Solution 2** (Boot button)

> Push and hold the boot button and apply power.
>
> http://www.elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack

from: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/beagleboard/_mOlo6T-70E